# How do I add a char device via C w/o resorting to a bash script

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, driver

I want to add a char device to `/devices` in my Linux directory via C code. Since I'm creating fictitious drivers that should only exist when I `insmod my_module.ko`, I want my module to create a device for me. Below is the part of my code which should add the device, but I only initialize my `cdev struct` and tell the kernel about it.

```
int start_mod(void){
    //Because we are dealing with a fictitious device, I want
    //the driver to create my two devices with arbitrarly 
    //assigned major numbers.

    alloc_chrdev_region(&dev_num, FIRST_MINOR, COUNT, DEVICE_NAME); // This assigns my device name
                                    // as well as asign Major # my driver uses

    cdev_init(&(my_dev->my_cdev), &fops);// This initializes my cdev struct that the kernel uses to keep track of my device
    my_dev->my_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    my_dev->my_cdev.ops = &fops;// fops is my file operations struct

    int err = cdev_add(&(my_dev->my_cdev), dev_num, COUNT);// this in theory should give a pointer to the kernel
    // to my cdev struct that I have setup to exist in my other structure.

    // Now I need to officially add my device to /devices folder.
    return 0;   
}
```

I'm not to sure what I need to do to officially add the char device to the kernel.

Comment: Use [mknod(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mknod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is you use some of the newer registration functions in the kernel like `class_create` and `device_create`. This will allow `udev` to create your device.

Are you saying you wrote a driver without looking at any other drivers?
Because there is no shortage of examples about how to register a character device.

Look in

```
drivers/char
```

Those aforementioned functions are GPL-only, by the way, which has implications if you want to redistribute the code.

Answer (score 2):

The `mknod()` system call used to be used...but only a `root`-privileged process can create devices in `/dev` usually.

Comment: Before I forget, is there also a way to remove that device when I exit_module?

Comment: The `unlink()` system call removes the entry created by `mknod()`.

Comment: I tried mknod but it can't find the header files I provided it. I'm guessing that since this is a user space fxn and therefor won't work for kernel module.

Comment: I said '`mknod()` is the _system call_' so yes, that is the user-side code.  Ditto for `unlink()`.  You'll need to work out how to make the kernel-side equivalent; you can look up the syscall entry points for `mknod()` and `unlink()` and work out what to call from there.

Comment: Stop! Kernel modules aren't supposed to create device nodes themselves. Read up on udev and you'll understand how this is supposed to work.